# Pass variable to append

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

On the homepage, the JS will grab up to three news stories from the news page, and will show abbreviated versions which will link to full story. The problem I'm running into is that one of the variables I'm attempting to concatenate is not doing so as intended.

Homepage:

```
<div id="news-autoloader">

</div>
```

Newspage:

```
<h3 id="news1">News Item 1</h3>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>

<h3 id="news2">News Item 2</h3>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>

// more or less of the same news items
```

The news page may have no items, but we will capture up to three, first the headline, and then n characters (would rather capture n words, but that's after this issue is resolved!) of the first p following the h3 headline.

```
<script>
$.get('company-news.html',
    function(data){
        var news1 = $(data).find('#news1 + p');
        var news2 = $(data).find('#news2 + p');
        var news3 = $(data).find('#news3 + p');

// see how many news items there are (there's probably a more graceful way of doing this!):

    if (news1.html() == null){
        var items = 0;
    } else if (news2.html() == null){
        var items = 1;
    } else if (news3.html() == null){
        var items = 2;
    } else {
        var items = 3;
    }

    if (items == 0){
        $('#news-autoloader').append('<h3>No News.</h3>');
    } else {
        for (i=1; i<=items; i++){
            var abc = '#news' + i;
            var def = 'news' + i;
            var url   = 'a href="company-news.html#news' +i;

            $('#news-autoloader').append($(abc,data)).append('<p>' + def.html().substr(0, 175) + ' <' + url + '">More</a></p>');
        }
    }
}, 'html');
</script>
```

Everything works - `abc` evaluates properly in the first append, but in our second append, variable `def` does not.

I would like to know three things:

1) How do I get `def` to work in the second append,

2) Is there a more graceful way find the number of news items,

3) How do I limit by number of words instead of characters (so abbreviated sentences are complete).

TIA!!!

Comment: forgot a $( ) around def?

Comment: If my answer solved your question, please accept it so that the question is not left open. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you called `...def.html()....` and `def` is neither a jQuery object or an element. Rather, the value of `def` is `'news' + i`, where `i` is the iteration number.

If your intention was to take the HTML from the element with the `id` of `news` then you need to change the value of `def` to `'#news' + i`, and then wrap `def` into a jQuery object, `$(def)`, function:

`...$(def).html()....`

**UPDATE**

If I misunderstood you again, and what you want to do is render the variables `news1`, `news2` and `news3`, then you should put those variables into an array.

You CANNOT reference a variable from a string in JavaScript without using an array.

If this is the case, your updated code will be as follows:

```
<script>
$.get('company-news.html',
    function(data){
        var newsData = [];
        newsData["news1"] = $(data).find('#news1 + p');
        newsData["news2"] = $(data).find('#news2 + p');
        newsData["news3"] = $(data).find('#news3 + p');

// see how many news items there are (there's probably a more graceful way of doing this!):

    if (newsData["news1"].html() == null){
        var items = 0;
    } else if (newsData["news2"].html() == null){
        var items = 1;
    } else if (newsData["news3"].html() == null){
        var items = 2;
    } else {
        var items = 3;
    }

    if (items == 0){
        $('#news-autoloader').append('<h3>No News.</h3>');
    } else {
        for (i=1; i<=items; i++){
            var abc = '#news' + i;
            var def = 'news' + i;
            var url   = 'a href="company-news.html#news' +i;

            $('#news-autoloader').append($(abc,data)).append('<p>' + $(newsData[def]).html().substr(0, 175) + ' <' + url + '">More</a></p>');
        }
    }
}, 'html');
</script>
```

Comment: My intention at this point is `... .append('<p>' + news1.html(). ...` `... .append('<p>' + news2.html(). ...` `... .append('<p>' + news3.html(). ...` via the variable `def` and the iteration number...

Answer (score 1):

1
Change `def.html()` to `$(abc).html()` as its not yet a JQuery object

2 You could store each news object in an array and then loop through that to add your items.

```
var newsItems = [];  
for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++){  
    var newsElem = $(data).find('#news' + i + ' + p');  
    if(newsElem.html() != null){  
        newsItems.push(newsElem);  
    }  
}
```

3 Depending on the contents of def something like this may work to get the first 10 words. the `text()` will strip HTML tags so if you need to preserve those it will be more work.

```
$(newsItems[i]).text().split(' ').slice(0,10);
```

Comment: I get undefined when I change to `$(def).html()`.

Comment: Because it should be `$(newsItems[def])` as it is in my answer - he just forgot to put it in

Comment: +1 for the `html() -> text()` as this gets rid of any images news editor may put into a story! However, still working on the split and slice part as that is turning this: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...` into: `Lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit,amet,,consectetur,adipiscing,elit.,`.

Comment: Look into adding .join(' ') after the slice